# Are there animals that can deliberately manipulate their metabolism, apart from hibernation?

Tags: metabolism

Are there animals that can slow down their metabolism deliberately? I know that hibernation would be one mechanism, and maybe being cold-blooded, but I was wondering if there was maybe an animal that could crank up or slow down metabolism based on food resources?

Are there chemical compounds that could have this effect?

Comment: By deliberately do you mean voluntarily? Pythons [are known](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/211/24/3767) to modulate their metabolism. Are you looking for examples like this?

Comment: Yes, sorry, voluntarily would be a better word!

Comment: [Humans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=389c31dD9xg).